# Cron does not run script built on Actiona

Tags: bash, cron

Actiona is a software for creating macros. I created a script in it, very simple, just to move the mouse cursor and make a few clicks.

The script, when run on the terminal, works:

`/usr/bin/actexec /home/ronald/xmacro/entrada.ascr`

I created a `cron` process to execute the same line above, but `cron` does, but it's as if `actexec` does not start.

See my line of code made in Crontab:

```
/usr/bin/actexec /home/ronald/xmacro/entrada.ascr > /home/ronald/xmacro/output.log
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit 1:

This is script used:

```
#!/bin/sh /usr/bin/actexec /home/ronald/xmacro/entrada.ascr > /home/ronald/xmacro/output.log
```

Comment: Perhaps you written script has errors!

Comment: The cron environment is  different from your terminal environment. Most failed scripts rely upon some element of the terminal environment (login account, display, home dir, etc) that cron simply doesn't know. Your script must be explicit and assume nothing.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, your best bet is to set a pause action / timer in the Actiona gui instead of using cron to run a task.
For Windows use the export executable script option to make an executable.exe, than you can run cron.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running script inside bash, run

```
actiona /home/user/your_action.ascr -e -x -E
```